# Triggering Jenkins build when the status of all the issues under a particular JIRA project is changed to "IN PROGRESS" state

Tags: jenkins, jira

I have a scenario where a Jenkins build should get triggered automatically **only** when all the issues under a particular JIRA project are changed to **" IN PROGRESS"** state. Let's say I have 3 issues under my JIRA project, where 2 of them are in **"TO DO"** state, and one of them is in **" IN PROGRESS"** state. A Jenkins build should only be triggered when the remaining 2 tickets also move from **"TO DO"** to **"IN PROGRESS"**

I can trigger the Jenkins build automatically for individual issue status change by using the JIRA webhook and JIRA trigger plugin in Jenkins by selecting the option of **Build when an issue is updated in JIRA** and passing the required parameter in Jenkins job, but I need a condition where build should happen only when **all** issues(and not just one) for a particular project are updated to **" IN PROGRESS"** in JIRA. Is it possible to have something like this?

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is to use JIRA's REST API and poll every x minutes to check if all issues that match your query are in "IN PROGRESS" status. You can even combine those two - after you receive a call from JIRA's webhook you can respond by calling REST API to check statuses.